# How to display the number of data based on today date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php  

   $connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","halcondentalclinic");
                             $queryss="SELECT datetreat FROM alltreatment WHERE datetreat order by date(now())";

                             $query_runsss=mysqli_query($connection,$queryss);

                             $rowsss=mysqli_num_rows($query_runsss);
                             echo '<h1>'.$rowsss.'</h1>';
                            ?>
```

[image: screeanshot1]

This is the datetreat table in my database

[image: screenshot2]

This is the output of my dashboard but I want to display the number of the treated patient on today's date but on my dashboard, the output is 4 but my expected output is 1 because of the data based on the today's date

Comment: `WHERE datetreat` doesn't do anything useful. If you want to restrict it to today, then you need to compare `datetreat` to something else. e.g. write `WHERE datetreat = date(now())` would make sense. P.S. your question has nothing to do with Javascript or HTML, I've amended your tags.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE datetreat` doesn't do anything useful. If you want to restrict it to today, then you need to compare datetreat to something else. e.g.

```
WHERE datetreat = date(now())
```

would make sense